# Progress bar around all viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a "full screen" progress bar : a 100% x 100% border who just fill in. Not easy to explain so i've made a quick draw.

http://hpics.li/998ef2e

Thanks a lot for ure ideas !

Comment: From top left to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I crafted a solution using four divs, which approximates closely enough I think:
https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/jexb9egm/

```js
var i=0;

var myVar=setInterval(function () {myTimer()}, 10);

function myTimer() {
    i++;
    if(i<=100){
    $("#top").css("width", i+"%");
    }else if(i<=200){
    $("#right").css("height", (i-100)+"%");
    }else if(i<=300){
    $("#bottom").css("width", (i-200)+"%");
    }else if(i<=400){
    $("#left").css("height", (i-300)+"%");
     }else{
     clearInterval(myVar);
    }
}
```

```css
#main, html, body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.loadbar{
    background-color:#f00;
    position:absolute;
}

#top, #bottom{
    height:20px;
}

#left, #right{
    width:20px;
}

#top{
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#right{
    top:0;
    right:0;
}

#bottom{
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}

#left{
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div id="loader">
        <div id="top" class="loadbar">
        </div>
        <div id="right" class="loadbar">
        </div>
        <div id="bottom" class="loadbar">
        </div>
        <div id="left" class="loadbar">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(just incrementing from 0 to 400 here, use your progress percent*4 instead)

Comment: it does the job, thank you ! You think its possible to use it according to the reading of my audio player (like this way : http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/DCE6N/7/)

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/Lo0hq0xw/](https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/Lo0hq0xw/) Note that I kept the update on a regular timer, and also keeping the multiplier of 4, as the update on the audio wasn't frequent enough for a fluid animation and also lead to the bars not loading enough,

Comment: Great @Ben : https://jsfiddle.net/angelilo_/Lo0hq0xw/2/
it only remains to put everything back to zero in a second listening

Comment: Had already started that, here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/o8go5ocs/

Comment: we arrived at the same point, however, one button to play / pause with this method seems complex

Comment: I updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/o8go5ocs/). We do not want to needlessly reset the whole thing, that's why I added the checks to see if it was really paused while playing or if we were playing from the beginning.
I trust you can take it from here :) The original question was answered anyway :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78264/discussion-between-ben-philipp-and-angelilo).

Comment: hi, I would like to propose a second podcast in the same page on the same principle (on a screen below) but this is not working. Any idea ?

Comment: Do you have a live link?
An apparent conflict would be: What if there are two sources playing at once, or if one is playing while the other one is paused at not 0 or 100?
Let us continue this conversation [in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78264/discussion-between-ben-philipp-and-angelilo)

Comment: hi @ben, still around?

Comment: Yes. Better join me in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93729/room-for-ben-philipp-and-angelilo

Answer (score 0):

Although I've never seen this done, you could *probably* create this effect using Divs that disappear as the page loads. Basically, put a solid color as the background, and use a white div across each side (top left to top right, top right to bottom right, bottom right to bottom left, bottom left to top left) that shrinks as loading completes. This is the same effect as if the colored bar 'loaded' across the screen.

This may be a lot of work for a purely cosmetic effect.